# Drop spam flag lock action limit from 6 flags to 4

Tags: feature-request, spam

I'll admit, I haven't looked at the data, but I don't think there are many times the 6 flag lock limit was used as opposed to a mod dropping in with a binding flag.

Can the limit be dropped to something more in grasp of the current community?

From [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work)

> The spam flag is designed to eliminate posts with no relevant content and to penalize the authors:
>
> - 3 flags (spam or offensive): post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags (spam or offensive): post is [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.
> - 1 flag from a moderator has the same effect as 6 flags from normal users: instant destruction.
> - Because a question with 6 flags is locked, a 10k reputation user cannot meaningfully undelete it.
> - Each spam flag counts as a downvote for calculating the post's score *(it does not affect the user's reputation)*.

Comment: It has been quite spammy lately. So, given the number of active users, you want it to have more impact.

Comment: Related = http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193353/better-tools-to-handle-spam-on-low-traffic-sites

Comment: @pnuts Nope :) Stack Exchange Inc doesn't really care, I figured that out a long time ago. I realize that I haven't responded to a few requests mainly because I don't have an authoritative answer I can give you.

Comment: Stack Overflow Inc only cares for Stack Overflow, that post seems SO specific. Wait I mean Stack Exchange Inc, actually they've changed their name so many times I guess it's the same thing.